# using html elements in Raphael and set events

Tags: html, svg, raphael

I'm using Rapahel js to create some svg which contain html elements, I found raphael-infobox and it is cool but can't set hover ( mouseenter + mouseleave ) event on it.

can some help please!?

Comment: can's set event while using raphael-infobox, can't use html elements in raphael because of .text()

looking for something like this https://www.worldwealthreport.com/ ( the circles )

Comment: Please create a [mcve] showing what you've got so far and add it as markup (i.e. not a link) to the question itself.